# OCaml Function Writing: Use recursion and list pattern matching to define a function exists with the following type:

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, pattern-matching, ocaml

Use recursion and list pattern matching to define a function exists with the following type:
   exists : (’a -> bool) -> ’a list -> bool
The function should have the following behavior: for any predicate (function with boolean range) p and list l, a well-typed invocation (exists p l) should evaluate to true iff there exists some element x of l for which p x evaluates to true.

I am new to OCaml and do not know where to begin, any help would be great.

Comment: I like to be helpful, but I have to believe you're taking a class that provides some sort of material that will help you learn enough OCaml to do the assignment. This will be much more effective than starting from zero information here on SO. Provide some code that you wrote yourself and explain why it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: There is a such function in the module `List` of `OCaml`. Maybe if you're using it on some dummy examples, you may have an idea to how solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
#let rec exists p = function
    []            -> false
  | x::_ when p x -> true
  | _::tl         -> exists p tl;;

val exists : ('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> bool = <fun>
```

test :

```
# exists ((=)2) [4;3;2;1];;
- : bool = true
# exists ((=)2) [1;4];;
- : bool = false
```

About pattern matching :

```
let is_one = function
   1 -> true
 | x -> false
```

or

```
let is_one = function
   1 -> true
 | _ -> false    (* _ in any case *)
```

or

```
let is_one = function
   x when x=1 -> true
 | _          -> false
```

test

```
# is_one 1;;
- : bool = true
```

Comment: Thank you! I am having a difficult time understand pattern matching and was wondering if you could elaborate on the function?  Would be greatly appreciated!